# Executable, executor: correct way to stress syllables

Tags: word-stress

Google, when searching for `executable define` or `executor define` shows that second syllable is stressed, i.e. exEcutable, exEcutor.

Speech on http://www.thefreedictionary.com/executable suggests that `exEcutable` is British and `execUtable` is American.

Single variant on https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/executable is `exEcutable`.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HivZxn5bwa8 -- `execUtable`.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/executable -- `Executable` as British and `execUtable` as American.

All my colleagues -- `execUtable`.

Is it dependent on whether it's British or American?

Can it be generalised to more common rule?

Comment: For the sake of *comprehensiveness*: adjective/noun "executable": Webster (the dot after the *d* doesn't denote stress, I think; AmE): `/ˈeksəˌkyüd.əbəl, -ütə-, ˌ ̷ ̷ ̷ ̷ˈ ̷ ̷ ̷ ̷ ̷ ̷/`; OED: `/ɛkˈsɛkjʊtəb(ə)l/`; (formerly known as) New Oxford Dictionary of English (BrE): `/ɪɡˈzɛkjʊtəb(ə)l, ɛɡˈzɛkjʊtəb(ə)l/` MacMillan (AmE): `/ˈeksəˌkjutəbl/`; The New Oxford American Dictionary (AmE): `/ˈeksəˌkyo͞odəb(ə)l/` Longman (specifically noun, should that make a difference; AmE, then BrE): `/ˈeksəkjuːtəbəl, ˈeksɪkjuːtəbəl/` . `ˈ` and `ˌ` denote primary and secondary stress, respectively.

Comment: In AmE, executable is either of the two you posted.  It's possible that it is exEcutable when talking about the noun (a program's executable), and exeCUtable when talking about the adjective (an executable function), but it might also just be personal preference.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm American and I've never heard *executable* pronounced with stress on the second syllable, only on the third.

Comment: But what would be the correct way to pronounce "executed". On which syllable is the stress?

Answer (score 2):

*Executive* is pronounced *exECutive.*  This is a noun that typically means a high-ranking person in a company, or something that facilitates execution.  You can't pronounce this *exeCUTive*.

*Execute* and related forms are pronounced *exeCUTE*, e.g. *execUTEd*, *exeCUTing*, *exeCUTion* and cannot be pronouned with the stress elsewhere.

*Executable* is derived from *execute*, not *executive*.  The *-able* form of *executive* would be *executivible* which isn't a word.

So logically it should be pronounced *exeCUTEable* but pronouncing it the other way isn't really wrong, just logically inconsistent.